# Write to coredata clearing old values

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, uitableview

I am trying to write single values to a coredata object that contains 6 values. My coredata controller write method for this entity looks like this

```
- (void)writeSearchObj:(NSString *)value Name:(NSString *)name
{
    // WRITE TO CORE DATA
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];

    SearchObj *SearchObj = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"SearchObj" inManagedObjectContext:context];

    if ([name isEqualToString:@"CurrMac"]) {
        SearchObj.currMac = value;
    } else if ([name isEqualToString:@"CurrStarting"]) {
        SearchObj.currStarting = value;
    } else if ([name isEqualToString:@"CurrSelected"]) {
        SearchObj.currSelected = value;
    } else if ([name isEqualToString:@"CurrID"]) {
        SearchObj.currID = value;
    } else if ([name isEqualToString:@"CurrNumber"]) {
        SearchObj.currNumber = value;
    } else if ([name isEqualToString:@"ICurr"]) {
        SearchObj.iCurr = value;
    }

    NSError *error = nil;
    [self.managedObjectContext save:&error];
}
```

Then I use it like this

```
[coreDataController writeSeriesSearchObj:selectedRowString Name:@"CurrMac"];
```

The issue here is that when I only write one value every other value is lost. 
I need to be able to remember the old values..

to get an idea of the structure of my views and when I am trying to write
I have a main view which is a tableviewcontroller and two tableview subviewControllers

-Main view -- this has two tableviewcells, one that takes you to MacView and the other that takes your to CurrIDView. You must select a MacView value before you can go to CurrIDView but once a MacView has been set you can go straight to CurrIDView if needed

- MacView
  -- 10 constant values to select from
- CurrIDView
  -- values here change depending what value was selected in MacView

I hope the view explination helps with any possible solution.

Comment: In code, you are creating a new object.  Your prose suggests you want to edit an existing object.  Which is it?

Comment: I would like to edit an existing object.. sorry my coredata is pretty weak.. trying to work on it.. but bit caught up here.

Comment: If you have a pointer to an object, you could just use `setValue:forKeyPath` with your if-elses, though using a setter would be better.   But the crux here is... I don't see a pointer to the object you want to edit.

Comment: To update to existing object either keep the reference to created object and update using  `setValue:forKeyPath ` or fetch object from database using search criteria, [here is documentation on how to fetch](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdFetching.html)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20020442/querying-core-data-for-specific-attributes-when-creating-new-objects-and-returni (for fetching rather than already having a pointer)